# MVC + SQLite : UPDATE doesn't work. Syntax?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm programming a library application in MVC. I'm using for the first time connection to a database and **Dapper**. MVC to SQLite

My database looks like :

- Table name: SubscriberBook
- Columns: SubscriberId / BookId / BorrowDate / ReturnDate

When a borrow is create, **ReturnDate** is set to null.

When a subscriber returns a book, I want to keep others data and UPDATE **ReturnDate** with the current date, like DateTime.now.Ticks.

Model :

```
public class SubscriberBookEntity
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int SubscriberId { get; set; }
    public DateTime BorrowDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller, call Create + Update :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubscriberBorrow(Borrow borrow)
    {
        SubscriberEntity subscriberEntity = new SubscriberEntity();
        SubscriberBookEntity subscriberBookEntity = new SubscriberBookEntity();
        List<SubscriberBookEntity> subscriberBookEntityList = new List<SubscriberBookEntity>();
        subscriberBookEntityList = Manager.GetAllBorrow();

            foreach (Book borrowBook in borrow.Library.BookList)
            {
                if (borrowBook.IsChecked && Error == false)
                {
                    subscriberBookEntity.DateEmprunt = DateTime.Now;
                    subscriberBookEntity.DateRetour = new DateTime();

                    Manager.CreateBorrow(borrow.SelectedSubscriberId, borrowBook.Id, subscriberBookEntity.DateEmprunt, subscriberBookEntity.DateRetour);
                    subscriberBookEntityList = Manager.GetAllBorrow();
                }
            }

        if (borrow.Button.Equals("Return"))
        {
            foreach (Book borrowBook in borrow.Library.BookList)
            {
                if (borrowBook.IsChecked)
                {
                    subscriberBookEntity.ReturnDate = DateTime.Now;
                    Manager.UpdateBorrow(subscriberBookEntity);
                }
            }
```

Create :

```
public static void CreateBorrow(int subscriberId, int bookId, DateTime dateEmprunt, DateTime dateRetour)
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Execute("INSERT INTO SubscriberBook (SubscriberId, BookId, DateEmprunt) VALUES (@subscriberId, @bookId, @dateEmprunt)",
            new
            {
                SubscriberId = subscriberId,
                BookId = bookId,
                DateEmprunt = dateEmprunt.Ticks,
            });
        }
    }
```

Get :

```
public static List<SubscriberBookEntity> GetAllBorrow()
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            return connection.Query<SubscriberBookEntity>("SELECT BookId, SubscriberId FROM SubscriberBook").ToList();
        }
    }
```

Update :

```
public static void UpdateBorrow(SubscriberBookEntity subscriberBookEntity)
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            if(subscriberBookEntity != null)
            {
                connection.Execute("UPDATE SubscriberBook SET ReturnDate = @returnDate WHERE BookId = @bookId AND SubscriberId = @subscriberId",
                new
                {
                    returnDate = subscriberBookEntity.ReturnDate.Ticks,
                    bookId = subscriberBookEntity.BookId,
                    subscriberId = subscriberBookEntity.SubscriberId,
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I got no error but nothing changes in my database. The value of ReturnBorrow is still at null.

Thanks for your patience and your help.

Comment: Are you using Dapper? Can you get the return value of the Execute method and check if it is different than zero?

Comment: How is `subscriberBookEntity` constructed and filled?

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late but i can't launch my app anymore. IIS Express won't start...
I have update my post with the methode who filled subscriberBookEntity. And yes i'm using dapper.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations, my code in the controller for "return" does not use correct variables.

After corrections :

```
if (borrow.Button.Equals("Retourner"))
        {
            foreach (SubscriberBookEntity subscriberBookEntity in subscriberBookEntityList)
            {
                foreach(Book borrowBook in borrow.Library.BookList)
                {
                    if(borrowBook.IsChecked && borrowBook.Id == subscriberBook.BookId && subscriberBook.SubscriberId == borrow.SelectedSubscriberId)
                    {
                        subscriberBook.DateRetour = DateTime.Now;
                        Manager.UpdateBorrow(subscriberBook);
                    }
                }
            }

            List<SubscriberBookEntity> SubscriberBookEntityList = Manager.GetAllBorrow();

        }
```

Thanks to @Steve and @Patrick Hofman for thier advices.